# transferring file through a network without asking for password

Tags: scripts

I am new to write scripts in linux.
I would like to copy some file from a linux machine into a FreeNAS everyday without prompting for password. how should I do that?
should I map a network drive?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Rsync with SSH keyfiles maybe ? How large/how. many files ? Are both systems always on ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, there are always on. Files are 2 or 3 for every day and at most 500MB. I tried to use the following command: 
'rsync $args --password-file=rsync_pass_file user@remoteMachine::/share localdirectory'   
but it result with errors:
ERROR: The remote path must start with a module name not a /
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1666)

Comment: If that `rsync $args --password-file=rsync_pass_file user@remoteMachine::/share localdirectory` is the original commands then I see two issues: 1) ` --password-file=` is used in connection with rsync deamon - is that your setup ? 2) the "::" is wrong, only one ":" and it has to be an absolute path

Comment: '::' is a typo, sorry. But about the first issue, what should I do exactly?

Comment: have a look [here at Backup with rsync and SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync). There are many other useful things there but **Backup with rsync and SSH** is what I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert for your help. I should read it.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer based on this

Comment: did it work for you ?

Comment: well, first of all, again thank you for your help.  I tried it and it worked for me, but before trying that I tried another way to do that: I mounted the remote network share permanently in which it is visible when you enter the 'df' command as a network drive and then I used 'rsync' (or 'scp') command to copy data into network drive.

Answer (score 1):

### Backup with rsync and SSH

---

*Disclaimer: There are many methods, this is my personally preferred one*

Make sure you have SSH up and running on your **destination** host (depending on how to install/start SSH on FreeNAS  - I don't know)

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Then see that you can login with keyfiles (without pw) and enter the following on your (source) Ubuntu Linux PC

`ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /home/username/.ssh/rsync_keyfile.dsa`

Don't set a password, just hit enter twice !

*Disclaimer: I would normally advice to use passwords, but not for scripting purposes*

Now we copy the key from the *source-* to the **destination-host**, here you have to enter the pw for *dst-user* once

`ssh-copy-id -i /home/username/.ssh/rsync_keyfile.dsa dst-user@destination-host`

You can test it, to see if it works and if you can login

`ssh -i  /home/username/.ssh/rsync_keyfile.dsa dst-user@destination-host`

then you can transfer files with

`rsync -<rsync options> -e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/rsync_keyfile.dsa" /local/backup/files/* dst-user@destination-host:/remote/backup/`

I would suggest using `-a` as well as `-u`,`-h`and `-P`.

These options tell rsync to **a**rchive (a good combination of options), only **u**pdate (copy) files that are newer on the source than the destination, make it **h**uman readable and show us the **p**rogress of the whole transfer.

If you use this in a script, make sure that the user executing said script is owner of the rsync_keyfile.dsa, otherwise it won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

SSH would be a simple approach. You could use the file browser to connect to networked devices through sftp (SSH FTP for short) - ubuntu's file browser is nautilus and it is capable of doing this.

You can find some basic information and configuration for ssh from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/)

Once you have the keys generated and added to your server's authorized keys list, click on `Other Locations` from the bottom part of the left panel and the "Connect to Server" box should pop up to allow you to connect through sftp.

[image]

To explain the highlighted content in red:

- `sftp://` is the transfer protocol.
- `git` is the user on the server. I have a user created named git on my server. Depending on your ssh server configuration, you may only want to allow connections to specific users on the server.
- `homeserver` is the alias for my server which is configured through the hosts file in `/etc/hosts`
- `/home/git` is the directory that will initially open up when I click connect.

You can bookmark the connection so that you can open it whenever you want.

[image]